# Do I need to free auto-created form in Delphi?

Tags: forms, free, destroy, delphi-xe3

I set a form(not the main form) as auto-created in the project. It seems that I do not need to free it manually when the main form is destroyed. If I do so, then I will get "Invalid Pointer" error. I do not see any document mention that.

Comment: You don't "need" to destroy any object that is owned, if the ownership chain leads to an object that is destroyed. In the situation you describe the owner is the application object which is destroyed. The thing is though, is that you can normally destroy owned objects. Perhaps there's an issue with your code. Without an [mcve] we can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All *auto-created* Form objects are owned by the `TApplication` object.  It will free them for you when itself is freed.  But if you want to free them yourself beforehand, it is safe to do so, provided you don't try to access them after you free them (which, it sounds like you are).  When freed, they will remove themselves from the `TApplication` object so it does not try to free them again.